# Why is this tkinter program freezing?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm having an issue with my GUI freezing, and I don't know why. The `run` method is not releasing the lock.

**Demo program**

```
import time
import threading
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

LOCK = threading.Lock()

class Video(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Video, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.frame = tk.DoubleVar(root, value=0)
        self.frames = 1000

    def run(self):
        while True:                
            with LOCK:   
                position = self.frame.get()

                if position < self.frames:
                    position += 1
                else:
                    position = 0

                self.frame.set(position)                

            time.sleep(0.01)

root = tk.Tk()
video = Video()
root.minsize(500, 50)

def cb_scale(_):
    with LOCK:
        print('HELLO')

scale = ttk.Scale(
    root, from_=video.frame.get(), to=video.frames, variable=video.frame,
    command=cb_scale)

scale.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

**Problem**

Spam-clicking the progress bar freezes the program.

**Attempts at debugging**

1. I used [`mttkinter`](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter) by adding `import mttkinter` to the import statements and the problem persists. The issue is the lock not being released.
2. I inserted print statements to find out where exactly the program freezes.

Program with print statements:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import threading
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

def whichthread(say=''):
    t = threading.current_thread()
    print('{}{}'.format(say, t))

LOCK = threading.Lock()

class Video(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Video, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.frame = tk.DoubleVar(root, value=0)
        self.frames = 1000

    def run(self):
        while True:
            whichthread('run tries to acquire lock in thread: ')
            with LOCK:
                whichthread('run acquired lock in thread: ')

                position = self.frame.get()

                if position < self.frames:
                    position += 1
                else:
                    position = 0

                self.frame.set(position)
            whichthread('run released lock in thread: ')

            time.sleep(0.01)

root = tk.Tk()
video = Video()
root.minsize(500, 50)

def cb_scale(_):
    whichthread('cb_scale tries to acquire lock in thread: ')
    with LOCK:
        whichthread('cb_scale acquired lock in thread: ')
        print('HELLO')
    whichthread('cb_scale released lock in thread: ')

scale = ttk.Scale(
    root, from_=video.frame.get(), to=video.frames, variable=video.frame,
    command=cb_scale)

scale.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

This produces the following output right before the program freezes:

```
...
run tries to acquire lock in thread: <Video(Thread-1, started daemon 140308329449216)>
run acquired lock in thread: <Video(Thread-1, started daemon 140308329449216)>
cb_scale tries to acquire lock in thread: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140308415592256)>
```

This shows that for some reason, the `run` method does not release the lock.

3. I tried to comment out lines in order to narrow the problem down.

Removing any of the two `with LOCK` statements fixes the issue. Unfortunately, in my real program the `run` and `cb_scale` function do something meaningful that requires locking.

**Commenting out both the calls to `get` and `set` in `run` fixes the issue.**

... and this is where I am stuck! :)

**EDIT**

Thanks to [Mike - SMT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7475225/mike-smt) I was able to track the problem down further.

Using

```
class DummyDoubleVar(object):
    def get(self):
        return 500

    def set(self, _):
        pass
```

and

```
self.frame = DummyDoubleVar()
```

in `Video.__init__` prevents the program from freezing.

(Remember that the original program reliably freezes even with [`mttkinter`](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter). I am stumped what's going on here!)

Comment: @mike-smt Thank you, your comment helped me track down the problem further (see edit of question). Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Well keep in mind that tkinter is a single threaded application. So when you have something like `sleep()` or a `while` loop it will always block the mainloop of tkinter. My guess here is that likely your while loop or the LOCK in the loop is causing the freeze. Consider not using threading and use `after()` instead.

Comment: @Mike-SMT The `while` loop with the `sleep` inside the thread does not block the `Tkinter` mainloop. You can test this by adding a dummy button and setting the sleep time really high. The dummy button is still clickable.

Comment: Right but when dealing with the Variable that is part of the main thread is my thought  on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post, I will show the solution to the problem and what led me to discover it. It involves going over CPython `_tkinter.c` code, so if that's not something you are up for, you can just skip to the **TL;DR** section below. Now, let's dive down the rabbit hole.

**Lead-Up**

The problem occurs only when moving the sliding bar manually. The `MainThread` and the `Video`-thread are then in dead-lock with each other over the `LOCK`, which I will call the user-lock. Now, the `run` method never releases the user-lock after is has acquired it, which implies that is hanging because it is waiting for another lock or some operation to complete which cannot. Now, looking at the log output of your verbose example, it becomes clear that the program does not hang consistently: It takes a few tries.

By adding more prints to the `run` method, you may discover that the problem is not consistently caused by either `get` or `set`. When the problem is caused, `get` may have already finished, or it may not have. This implies that the problem is not caused by `get` or `set` specifically, rather by some more generic mechanism.

**Variable.set and Variable.get**

For this section, I considered only Python 2.7 code, even though the problem is also present in Python 3.6. From the [`Variable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py#L269)-class in the `Tkinter.py` file of CPython 2.7:

```
def set(self, value):
    """Set the variable to VALUE."""
    return self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, value)
def get(self):
    """Return value of variable."""
    return self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)
```

The `self._tk` attribute is the Tk-object defined in the C-code of Tkinter, and for the code of `globalgetvar` we must jump back to [`_tkinter.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_tkinter.c#L2046):

```
static PyObject *
Tkapp_GlobalGetVar(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return var_invoke(GetVar, self, args, TCL_LEAVE_ERR_MSG | TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
}
```

Jumping to [`var_invoke`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_tkinter.c#L2046):

```
static PyObject*
var_invoke(EventFunc func, PyObject *selfptr, PyObject *args, int flags)
{
    #ifdef WITH_THREAD
      // Between these brackets, Tkinter marshalls the call to the mainloop
    #endif
    return func(selfptr, args, flags);
}
```

Just to make sure: I compiled Python with thread support and the problem persists. The call is marshalled to the main thread, which I checked with a simple `printf` in that location. Now, is this done correctly? The function `var_invoke` will wait until the MainThread has resumed and has executed the requested call. What is the MainThread doing at this point? Well, it is executing its queue of events, in the sequence it got them. What sequence did it get them in? That depends on the timing. This is what causes the problem: In some cases, Tkinter will execute the call to the callback right before a `get` or `set`, but while the lock is held.

Regardless of whether `mtTkinter` is imported (as long as Python is compiled `WITH_THREAD` support), the call of `get` and `set` is marshalled off to the mainloop, but that mainloop may just be trying at that moment to call the callback, which also needs the lock... This is what causes the deadlock and your problem. So basically `mtTkinter` and plain Tkinter offer the same behaviour, though for `mtTkinter` this behaviour is caused in the Python code and for plain Tkinter it happes in C-code.

**TL;DR; In short**

The problem is caused by only the user-lock. Neither GIL nor the Tcl-interpreter lock is involved. The problem is caused by the `get` and `set` methods marshalling their actual invocation off to the `MainThread` and then waiting for completion of the call by this `MainThread`, while the `MainThread` tries to do the events in order and execute the callback first.

Is this intended behaviour? Maybe, I'm not sure. I sure can see that with all the `ENTER_TCL` and `LEAVE_TCL` macro's in the `_tkinter.c` file, a better solution might be possible than the current one. For now though, there is no real work-around for this problem (bug? feature?) that I can see, apart from using `Tk.after(0, Variable.set)`, so that the `Video`-thread does not hold the lock while the `MainThread` might need it. My suggestion would be removing the `DoubleVar.get` and `set` invocations from the code where the lock is held. After all, if your program does something meaningful, it might not need to hold the lock while it sets the `DoubleVar`. Or, if that is not an option, you will have to find some other means of synchronizing the value, like a subclass of the `DoubleVar`. Which suits your needs best highly depends on your actual application.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know 100% why your program locks up when clicking on the slider however I suspect that it is due to the `tk.DoubleVar()` as this is part of the main thread.

Consider using `after()` instead.

See below example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Video(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.minsize(500, 50)
        self.daemon = True
        self.frames = 1000
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.vid_var = tk.DoubleVar(self, value=0)
        scale = ttk.Scale(self, from_=self.vid_var.get(), to=self.frames, variable=self.vid_var, command=self.cb_scale)
        scale.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.run()

    def cb_scale(self, var):
            print('HELLO', var)

    def run(self):
        position = self.vid_var.get()
        if position < self.frames:
            position += 1
            self.after(10, self.run)
        else:
            position = 0
        self.vid_var.set(position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Video().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of the `after` method.  I am working on a large program and rewriting it to schedule everything via `after` would take a considerable amount of time. That would be the last resort. In any case I am itching do understand *why* the program is freezing.

Comment: @actual_panda I would like to know as well. I just have not done enough with threading to have a solid 100% answer on that problem. I just know how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i found the solution.

Just create your own sleep function. 
like this -

```
from time import time
def sleep(timeforsleep):
    global root
    starttime = time()
    while True:
        if (starttime <= time()-timeforsleep):
            break
        else:
            root.update()
```

and then use `sleep(2)`

and then remember to change `import time` to `from time import time`

**Easy Peasy**